# Azure Pipelines to build multiple solutions in a single repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is is possible to create a single YAML file to build multiple projects within my repository?

I have a repo with 12 solutions, each with a minimum of 6 projects within them. The repository is quite complex and without going into why it was developed like this, each solution is a dependency in a larger product.

Is it possible to build all of them with a single YAML file, instead of create a build pipeline for each of these projects? They need to be built in a certain order, as they are inter-dependent on one another.

On our local TeamCity environment, we leverage off an .msbuild file to do this, but I cannot find a way in Azure DevOps to do this

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the same basically build pipeline to happen to multiple repos?

Comment: Why not add 6 MSBuild tasks - to each solution?

Answer (score 0):

the better question is why? if you manage to do this with if's or something like that, your yaml file would be big and unmaintainable.

Why not just use a single file for each build? you can have many of them all targeting different files...

in the case your architect is mad, you can use something like this:

```
- ${{ if eq(Build.DefinitionName, 'something') }}:
  - task: something
    xxx
```

and you'd have several of this in the file, one for each solution. but this is an extremely crappy approach.

Comment: firstly, we don't want to waste too much effort to reproduce our TC environment on Azure DevOps, as this is a proof of concept. i prefer having each solution as a build, so that i can manage the docker deployments individually, however, it's a decision made by the architect of the project to contain the solutions build in a single run. from my investigation it's not a feasible solution, but i'd like to supply a concrete argument in favor of individual builds

Comment: he is mad, but i took the 'why' question to him and he went ... mmmm, maybe not the best approach :D. we've split our organization into the various individual projects, and have a build for each of those. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the YAML approach to build. But the YAML script would be huge and difficult to understand the dependencies. You can always use the Designer approach and pull out the system generated YAML if you are new to the system. Here's the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) reference that might help you!!!